# Move connected elements along their individuals Nomals

Tags: modeling

I saw that other users made almost the same question but always for a individuals faces, edges or vertex but, What happen when you select a connected faces, edges or vertex?
Like in Maya when you make your selection and move it with Ctrl+mmb

[image]

As I know in blender works for individual elements

[image]

But no for a selection of connected elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, the shink and fatten tool, will move vertices along their individual normals.